# Getting an Error for HTTP GET request in Javascript using XML HTTP request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-get

I'm new to Javascript. I'm trying to make a simple prompt website, and i'm trying to use a HTTP GET request to get an adjective from this site: https://random-word-form.herokuapp.com/

However, I always get a bad request error. I tried with a test API and watched several videos and used the same code they did to see if I could fix my issue but it still wouldn't work.

Help would be appreciated.

The javascript code is as follows:

```js
let adjective; 

function buttonclick(method, url){
    console.log("hi");
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);

    xhr.responseType = 'json';

    xhr.send();

    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(xhr.status!=200){
            alert('Error');
        }
        else {
            alert('got ${xhr.response.length');
        }
        let responseData = xhr.response;
        return responseData;
    };
};

function getData(){
    adjective = buttonclick('GET','https://random-word-form.herokuapp.com/random/adjective');
    console.log(adjective);
};

getData();
```

Comment: I've copied your code into a Stack Snippet. It doesn't produce a bad request error and does log a random word (as a single-element JSON array) to the console. Some things I would recommend, though: 1. Use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) rather than `XMLHttpRequest`. 2. Don't put `;` after function *declarations* (`;` is a *statement* terminator). 3. Hook event handlers *before* sending the request (becomes a non-issue if you switch to `fetch`). 4. Don't `return` anything from `onload` (again, non-issue if...).

Comment: 5. In the "else" branch, you seemed to mean to use a template literal, but you used a string literal instead. Read up on template literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). (Ignore the "(Template Strings)" part of that article title. Template literals are **not** strings. An untagged template literal does produce a string, but tagged ones don't.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you! I will do that :)

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using the `fetch` method.

```js
let loading = true
let error = false

function getData() {
  const url = 'https://random-word-form.herokuapp.com/random/adjective'
  fetch(url).then(res => {
    return res.json()
  }).then(res => {
     console.log(res) // <- here is your data aka response
  })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      error = true
    })
    .finally(() => {
      loading = false
    })
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getData()">get adj</button>
```

---

please keep in mind, if you're working with API's you should handle all possible states: `loading`, `success`, `error`. There are good articles out there that describes the basics.

What you should at least do, is:

1. show a loading state, if the response is correct, set loading to false
2. show a loading state, if the response got an error, set loading to false and error to true.

Answer (score 0):

You Would have to wait for `xhr.readyState` to be 4 with a listener.
It should be something like that :

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState === 4){
    // do Something 
    }
};
```